# How to install libxml2 in unix

Tags: xml, unix, solaris

can anybody tell me how to install libxml2 in Unix? I am using windows for browsing net and Unix for writing my C programs. I also dont know whether it is already installed. Please tell me guys how to install libxml2 and use it for parsing.

Comment: Generally speaking, you use whatever package manager your particular flavour of UNIX provides.

Comment: http://www.indexdata.com/metaproxy/doc/installation.html

Comment: WHAT unix system?  Are you running Linux, solaris, HPUX, SCO? which system? 

Once you share that we can probably help. You can do an ls to see if libxml2 is installed by checking to see if you have libxml2.a file in /usr/lib /usr/local/lib or /opt/lib or something like that the path will heavily depend on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the installation instructions that come with libxml2 in the file `INSTALL`.
If you find any file or directory with the substring `libxml2` in `/usr/local/include` or `/usr/local/lib` (such as `/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so`) then it is already installed.

Depending on the particular Unix brand (which you did not tell us), you might need to look in other directories as well.

Comment: Hi i am using solaris.. Go global for Unix.. client version 2.2.13.1093 220.. also i m using gnome and cde.. Also I am using windows for browsing.. so my downloaded file will be in windows.. can I copy it to unix? my internet does not seem to work in unix..

Comment: Hi guys I have  checked in /usr/include and I found libxml2.. So what should be the syntax in the header file. Is ir #include </usr/inlcude/xmllib2> ? Please help guys

Comment: You should instruct your compiler to search the proper directory, e.g. with `cc -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml ...` and then use, e.g., `#include <SAX.h>` if that is the header you want. How new are you to C programming? If you just started, what you are trying is a *major* task and you should ask a local C guru.

Comment: These header concepts are kinda new for me.. thanks for the reply.. one more doubt.. I used gcc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 xxx.c copied it from somewhere.. why should i write that lxml2? can you please tell me? without writing that i am getting errors

Comment: A header contains just declarations. A library contains the actual compiled code. The `-I` tells gcc where to look for headers, and `-l` tells it to link with a library. `-lFOO` will make a compiler search for a file named `libFOO.a` along some set of directories (to which you can add with `-L/some/directory`. Without `-lxml2` gcc will not link in `libxml2.a` which leads to unresolved symbols. By default, gcc will only link in `libc.a`, that's why you need `-lxml2`. You should read the C FAQ, at http://c-faq.com/ with lots of answers for common questions.

Comment: Good, then the next step is to click the up arrow above the "0" to mark this answer helpful and the green "check" below it to accept it.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to install from source - given by good folks at Cypress project.

https://github.com/projectcypress/cypress/wiki/Cypress-v2.0-Installation-Guide

---- for easy reading: copied from above URL ----

```
cd /tmp
wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
tar xzf libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
cd libxml2-2.8.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd
```

Comment: Did you find errors like "parser.c: In function 'xmlParseInNodeContext__internal_alias':" ..?

Comment: Or like "warning: redundant redeclaration of 'pthread_cond_signal'"? I can't install now, in Ubuntu